# ext4 issue on very old machine

Tags: linux, boot, memory, ext4, conversion

I'm trying to install Linux on a 20-year old Compaq HP Pavilion ze4300 with 256 MB RAM (I think) without internet connection.
I can boot from CD but not from USB.
Unfortunately I ran into this [excruciating problem](http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=111376).
Basically, my attempt at installing lubuntu resulted in ext4 hard disk file system.  Lubuntu doesn't have enough memory.  So then I tried Puppy Linux.  Everything is great, I could boot live and install, but the bootloader GRUB4DOS can't read ext4.  The instruction in the link to use GParted doesn't work, because I can't boot live GParted, presumably because machine is too old.

Question: Is there something extremely conservative that I can use on a 20-year old machine to change the ext4 back to ext3?  I know I can use a CD boot loader, but I really want to boot from HD.

Comment: You should state the most limiting factor: how much RAM?

Comment: Edited to specify 256MB. Thanks.

Comment: My idea would be to create (on a modern system) a VM with a 32 bits x86 CPU and 256MB RAM and see what you can manage to get working. You'll surely save time on each attempt

Comment: Is `mkfs.ext2` or `mkfs.ext3` available in Puppy Linux? In that case you can use one of those command line tools to create an `ext2` or `ext3` file system.

Comment: You may be "getting" to learn about raw use of `fdisk` soon...

Comment: Could you please provide list of commands that wipe off 100% of the hard disk and then create a single ext2 partition? It seems fdist and mkfs.ext2 do exist on puppylinux.  So I could boot live from CD, do that, reinstall, and hopefully boot. Thanks. [http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=14336&sid=1cc520648ed46305a8362fb1ef191443]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mke2fs -t ext3` to format a filesystem that is compatible with ext3 on older kernels. This will disable newer ext4 features.

Comment: That said, I don't really want to ask why you are trying to use such an old computer. The cost of electricity to run it probably exceeds the value of some newer computer/laptop that you could get from a recycling shop.

Comment: I didn't think of electricity. Thanks. I just had it in my room and thought of using -- I don't know of recycling shops near me.